# android studio webview to use javascript for the link

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

this question is how to apply java script by link to webview https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/lmibwymtkebspij/background.js after the page is fully loaded the background should turn green here is a sample code for loading the page

```
 webView = findViewById(R.id.Web);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

thank you in advance

Comment: `java != javascript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe someone will come in handy load the text of the script into the script variable using get request to link the address of the script like this:

```
     @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... path) {
        try {
            content = getContent(path[0]);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            content = ex.getMessage();
        }

        return content;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String content) {
        scriptbg = content;

        Log.d("debug", scriptbg);

    }

    public String getContent(String path) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            HttpsURLConnection c = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setReadTimeout(10000);
            c.connect();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(line + "\n");
            }
            return (buf.toString());
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

then we apply the script to our webView when the page is fully loaded like this:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + Script);
        Log.d("debug", "finish");
    }
```